# What licence to provide with code for possible employment?

Tags: software-industry, job-offer, australia

I am looking at getting my first full-time employment at a web design company. They have given me a design to recreate which they WILL be using in a presentation for a client.

My question is, what license should I provide with my work to cover myself, in the possible event they decide not to hire me and bite me on the ass for my work?

The entire design is still under my control and under my own personal domain. They have only visited the site. But they want control of the site which is what gives me the red flags; hence the need for this question regarding copyright law. For others interested I am in Australia. The company is also based within Australia

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111779/discussion-on-question-by-rightbehindu-what-licence-to-provide-with-code-for-pos).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your last comment was the last thing needed to trigger my Red Flag alert.

We can't answer the legal/license part on this site, but *to my personal taste*, this smells fishy; they are asking for many things, and even disclosed to you that this is going to be presented with a client...

I'd strongly suggest you consider if you are willing to give them full control, and if any, ask them why would they need full control... if it's going to be *showed* to a client they have no need at this point to get access to your code...

As someone suggested in comments, if you decide to give them full control I would strongly suggest you get some form of *written* guarantee that they commit to give you the job if you give them access, or at least that they commit to not using the code in the case you are not hired... this way you are covering your back at least minimally.

Again... several red flags... caution here.

Comment: Yep, smells like free consulting work disguised as an interview/audition.  I've seen plenty of people burned this way

Answer (score 14):

## This goes beyond 'Red-Flag'.  This is, 100%, a terrible flea-bag company

Why do I say that?  What sort of half-baked company would even think about using interview test material *to present to a prospective client?!*

Imagine trying to apply that logic anywhere else in your life:

- "I need to send a good resume to this potential employer.  I know
  I've already got an editor hired on our staff, but why not use it as
  an interview test for a first-time editor job applicant and send them
  that one?"
- "Wow - we're potentially going to land a contract making airplanes
  for the DoD!  Wait, no - why would have the prototype built in-house?
  We've got someone applying for an entry-level Aerospace Engineer
  position; let them draw up the specs instead as part of their
  interview process."
- "A bridal website is thinking about contracting us to make cookies
  for them!  Well, I mean, yeah, we could have our hired pastry chef do
  the trial batch... but why not having it be an interview test for the
  person applying for a first-time position as line cook?  They can
  make the cookies as part of their application, and we can send what
  they cooked over!  Win-Win!"

... not only is this company you're talking about a terrible flea-bag company that wants to use free labor in a commercial enterprise, ***but they don't even have the pride of workmanship to send clients their own effort***.  I can *sorta* understand a company being dirty enough to source-out the nitty-gritty gunk work to applicants (in a scummy underhanded way)... but for what they're using as show-off client demos?  That basically screams "We're incompetent and we know it!"